# Ошибка при попытке запуска .NET программы на Линуксе

Tags: linux, .net

Всем привет.

Я скачал нужное .NET SDK и Runtime для линукса. После чего я создал проект(Обычный, который выводит Hello World), и попытался запустить проект(`sudo dotnet run`). Но я получаю такую ошибку:

```
relocation error: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_fatal_printf version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

Гуглил ошибку, но нужного не нашел.

Comment: на какой Linux ставили, какую версию .net, как устанавливали?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Manjaro Linux, .NET 6.0, через snap.

Comment: Попробуй переустановить, но указать снапу параметр `--classic`.